# Issues with Flexslider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am trying to create a responsive slider using Flexslider. I am having a few issues though. I have the following settings set:

```
  $('.portfolio .flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: true,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 490,
    itemMargin: 30,
    minItems: 1,
    move: 1

  });
```

It doesn't seem to be applying `animationLoop: false`, it goes left first then right when you click the right directional nav link, and the heights seem to be all messed up sometimes when I load the page. You can see a preview here. Any thoughts what might be causing the issues?

http://staging.pautlerdesign.com/portfolio/index-test.php

Thanks for the help!

Comment: not able to explore through your page.http://staging.pautlerdesign.com/portfolio/index-test.php

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [Flexslider 2](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)?

Also, if your not actually displaying more than one item at a time you don't need the carousel parameters (`itemWidth`, `itemMargin`, `minItems`, `maxItems`, `move`) all you really need is:

```
$('.portfolio .flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: true,
    slideshow: false
});
```

You may also need to change your existing css for section.portfolio-piece .flexslider ul.slides li to:

```
section.portfolio-piece .flexslider ul.slides li {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This may fix the problem your seeing.